# Form submission on php custom templated system

Tags: php

We are using very simple php custom template system using oop approach, but when we submit form, its not getting `$_POST[]` results. Please have a look at main code...

```
switch($act) {     //$act= $_GET['Act'];
case 'Add':
$add_product = new Product();
print_r($_POST); 
if(!empty($_POST)) {
echo $_POST['name']; //to check if its getting value
}
include('templates/edit_product.tpl');
break;
}
```

and here is edit_product.tpl...

```
<form action="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>products.php?Act=Add" method="post">
<input type="text" size="50" name="name" />
<button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
```

thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>products.php?Act=Add" method="post">
<input type="text" size="50" name="name" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: form button has value already, using `<input type="submit"` and `<button type="submit"` are same thing. thanks.

Comment: Are they? Did not know that. Can you give me a source?

Comment: I meant something like http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/button.submit.html which shows that button can be used to submit a form too. Found it myself now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

we got the problem, Thanks. We were using `if(!empty($errors))` instead of `if(empty($errors))`